# In zend framework, what are the limits of using the table data gateway?

Tags: zend-framework

I was reading the zend framework tutorial by Rob Allen.  I am working on an application that will start small, but I would like it to be scalable, so the following statement got my attention:

> "For this tutorial, we are going to create a model that extends Zend_Db_Table and uses
>   Zend_Db_Table_Row. Zend Framework provides Zend_Db_Table which implements the Table Data
>   Gateway design pattern to allow for interfacing with data in a database table. Be aware though that the Table
>   Data Gateway pattern can become limited in larger systems. There is also a temptation to put database
>   access code into controller action methods as these are exposed by Zend_Db_Table."

Can anyone tell me how this would be limited for larger systems?  What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is the DataMapper. You have a good explanation of these different patterns here: [What is the difference between the Data Mapper, Table Data Gateway (Gateway), Data Access Object (DAO) and Repository patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804751/what-is-the-difference-between-the-data-mapper-table-data-gateway-gateway-da)

DataMapper is less coupled to the database that the Table Data Gateway which is a thin wrapper around a single table.

Zend_Db in ZF1 has serious limitations. Doctrine2 is a better choice for encapsuling your interaction with the persistence layer.